# Calculating total energy

Tags: mathematical-physics

I have the question:

> "Calculate the total energy of the moving object, when mass = $4$ kg, acceleration due to gravity = $9.81~\text{ms}^{-2}$, height = $10$ m and velocity = $3~\text{ms}^{-1}$"

I know that Total energy = potential energy + kinetic energy.
 Therefore, Total energy = $mgh + \frac{1}{2} mv^2$. However, the value for gravity is not given and I do not know how to calculate this using the following information given. I also do not know if my method of solving the problem is correct. The final units I get for total energy is [$\text{kg}^2\text{m}^2\text{s}^{-4}$].

Comment: The units for energy is $\text{J} = \frac{\text{kg}\cdot \text{m}^2}{\text{s}^2}$

Comment: The value for the acceleration due to gravity is given: $g=9.81 \; m/s^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the potential energy:  $E_P=mgh$, $m$ is the mass, $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity and $h$ is the height. So you know all you need and the units of measure are:
$$
[mgh]=kg \cdot \frac{m}{s^2}\cdot m =kg \cdot \left(\frac {m}{s} \right)^2
$$
, the same as for the kinetic energy.

Comment: I got the answer total energy = 410.4 [kgms^-2] is this correct ?

Comment: The value is correct, but the unit of measure is $kg\cdot m^2/s^2$ that is called **joule**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule